# Multi Search in ElasticSearch is not working correctly

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use [Multi Search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html#search-multi-search) of **elasticsearch**.

My `requests` file looks like below:

```
$ cat requests 
{"index" : "indexA"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 2}
{"index" : "indexB"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 2}
```

And I am using following `curl request`:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_msearch --data-binary @requests
```

Using this request, I only get the contents from `indexA` inside `response array`. The contents of `indexB` are completely ignored. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Did you make sure to add a new line character after the last line?

Comment: I tried by directly putting `\n` behind each line. But its not working. Am I doing it correctly ?

Comment: When you run `cat requests` simply add a new line after the last line and only then Ctrl+C.

Comment: Thanks that worked!! Please add an answer explaining the same so that I can accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run cat requests simply add a new line after the last line and only then Ctrl+C.

```
$ cat requests 
{"index" : "indexA"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 2}
{"index" : "indexB"}
{"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 2}
          <--- add a new line here
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I need to access `multi-search api` from my `application` *(using any HTTP library)*, do I always need to **create a file** and write my json query in it? Or is there some way I can create a `json array` containing queries and post that json body directly to ElasticSearch api ? I just want to know the `right practices` for using multi-search from inside an application.

Comment: It depends which client library you're using, but none of them requires to create a file prior to sending the query.

Comment: The client library I am using supports string body. Json also can be passed after converting to string. So can I append the jsons as a string with new line character between them ?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I am using `scala` and the `http library` is https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS